# cambio de divisa en tiempo real de MXN a USD tienda en linea para mostrar precios

Tags: java, angularjs, html5, spring, prestashop

tengo una tienda en linea y los precios de cada producto se muestran en dolares y a un costado se mostrara un "aprox" en pesos mexicanos como lo que hace aliexpress, o en su defecto quiero saber si para manejar estos cambios de divisa dependiendo del lenguaje que se seleccione, yo tengo que hacer el cambio manualmente, si es de mexico la persona se muestran los precios en pesos MXN y asi respectivamente por ahorita MXN y USD son las 2 divisas que menejaré, mas bien como hace el cambio de divisa esas paginas como amazon y aliexpress, hay que tener en cuenta que en precio del dolar cambia constantemente y se debe de actualizar el precio mexicano. 
estoy desarrollando en spring MVC, y angular js, y un poco de Servlets

Comment: Gracias lo checare

Comment: Juraría que Google tenia un servicio que te traducía en tiempo real diferentes divisas, lo que no se si todavía está activo

Comment: @PakoLordPakus www.google.com/finance pero no es el cambio oficial que toma el banco

Comment: Es cierto, pero creo recordar que como algo orientativo servía... no me hagais mucho caso, hace bastante que no lo uso....

Comment: Disculpame no me había dado cuenta utilizo la app para Android la acepte por que me sirvió no del todo,  sino a obtener ese cambio de divisa en tiempo  real,  y la acepto  por que de aquí yo la implemento

Comment: @Mariano   muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Ok estoy trabajando en eso gracias

Answer (score 2):

El Banco de México publicó un WebService con la cotización diaria del peso mexicano en:

http://www.banxico.org.mx/DgieWSWeb/DgieWS?WSDL

Este WebService lo podés consumir directamente desde Java. Este es un ejemplo sencillo de cómo se puede utilizar.

Pero tengo que hacer algunas salvedades. Para simplificar el ejemplo, personalmente preferí hacer directamente un request por HTTP POST para no caer en dependencias que no todos puedan usar. Asimismo, sobre el XML devuelto, estoy obteniendo los valores desde el string en crudo con un RegEx (sin usar un parser para el XML, sabiendo que podría romperse si cambia la estructura de la respuesta). Y tampoco estoy capturando posibles errores... Como verán, hay mucho para mejorar en este código. Se los dejo como tarea pendiente.

#### Código:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Banxico{

    //Variables del webservice http://www.banxico.org.mx/DgieWSWeb/DgieWS?WSDL
    private final String URL        = "http://www.banxico.org.mx/DgieWSWeb/DgieWS";
    private final String NS         = "http://ws.dgie.banxico.org.mx";
    private final String OPERATION  = "tiposDeCambioBanxico";
    private final String CHARSET    = "ISO-8859-1";
    private final String ENVELOPE = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"" + CHARSET + "\" standalone=\"no\"?>"
        + "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:apachesoap=\"http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap\" "
        + "xmlns:impl=\"" + NS + "\" xmlns:intf=\"" + NS + "\" xmlns:soapenc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" "
        + "xmlns:wsdl=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/\" xmlns:wsdlsoap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/\" "
        + "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" >"
        + "<SOAP-ENV:Body><mns:" + OPERATION + " xmlns:mns=\"" + NS + "\" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">"
        + "</mns:" + OPERATION + "></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
    private final static String REGEX = 
          "<bm:Series\\s++TITULO\\s*+=\\s*+\"(?<titulo>[^\"]*+)\""
        + "\\s++IDSERIE\\s*+=\\s*+\"SF43718\"[^>]*+>"
        + "\\s*+<bm:Obs\\s++TIME_PERIOD\\s*+=\\s*+\"(?<fecha>[^\"]*+)\""
        + "\\s++OBS_VALUE\\s*+=\\s*+\"(?<cotizacion>[^\"]*)";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Banxico http = new Banxico();

        String resultado = http.sendPost();

        procesarTexto(resultado);

    }

    // HTTP POST
    private String sendPost() throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(URL);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // Configuracion del Header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=" + CHARSET);
        con.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", OPERATION);

        // Enviar el request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(ENVELOPE);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        // Leer la respuesta
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // Devolver el XML
        return response.toString();
    }

    // Imprimir los datos
    private static void procesarTexto(final String uxml) {
        // Sacar las entities 
        //  (se rompe el XML pero es mas facil procesarlo directamente)
        String xml = unescapeCommonEntities(uxml);

        // Obtener los campos buscados con una expresion regular sobre todo el xml
        Pattern idPatt = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        Matcher m = idPatt.matcher(xml);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Cotizacion: " + m.group("cotizacion"));
            System.out.println("Fecha: " + m.group("fecha"));
            System.out.println("Descripcion: " + m.group("titulo"));
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
        }
    }

    // Funcion para decodificar las 5 entities mas comunes
    private static String unescapeCommonEntities( final String xmle )
    {
        return xmle.replaceAll( "&lt;", "<" )
                    .replaceAll( "&gt;", ">" )
                    .replaceAll( "&amp;", "&" )
                    .replaceAll( "&apos;", "'" )
                    .replaceAll( "&quot;", "\"" );
    }

}
```

#### Salida

```
Cotizacion: 18.7569                                                                                                                                                  
Fecha: 2016-07-25                                                                                                                                                    
Descripcion: Tipo de cambio Pesos por dólar E.U.A. Tipo de cambio para solventar obligaciones denominadas en moneda extranjera Fecha de determinación (FIX)
```

#### Demo online

<kbd>[Demo en tutorialspoint.com](http://goo.gl/4V0vIC)</kbd>

#### Descargo de responsabilidad

La verdad, desconozco completamente las condiciones de uso del webservice, ni cuan fiable es. Antes de usarlo en producción, recomiendo fehacientemente ver las condiciones del Banco e incluso contactarse con ellos para consultar. Si se usa este código o parte del mismo, queda bajo su propia responsabilidad.